# Binding to remote data with kendoUI and wordpress

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-dropdown

I've created a small wordpress snippet that echo's a json.
I'm trying to bind the json to a dropdownlist.
It doesn't work.
I took telerik's example, and just changed the URL and the fields names:
http://dojo.telerik.com/EtAr
Any idea why it's not working?

Answer (score 0):

You can see in the network tab  that the response that you received from the server is **not** a [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) response. It is an html response and somewhere inside of it you can see an element called data which contains a callback function which is never invoked.